# Regex Help - Trying to find vale/string after x amount of another pattern

Tags: regex

Regex is my nemesis, as I only have a need for it once every so often, I don't toy with it much.

Anyway, I am trying to find a Conference ID from a Meeting Body. The original string is in HTML, but I have used a utility class to "encode" it.

Here is the portion of the body I am interested in:

```
     &lt;p class=&quot;MsoNormal&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:10.5pt; 
     font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif; color:#252424&quot;&gt;Video Conference ID:
     &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Segoe 
     UI&quot;,sans-serif; color:#252424&quot;&gt;118 678 180 5
```

I want to find "Video Conference ID" and find the Value of (whatever) at the end of the second group (on the very next line), in this case, "118 678 180 5"

I am able to find the "Video Conference ID:, (`\bVideo Conference ID:\s+`) and some stuff (albeit the wrong stuff) after it.  I am trying to figure out how to get the value after the second `&gt;` (>) pattern.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: a Commenter provided the following.

```
(?s)\bVideo Conference ID:\s(?:.*?&gt;){2}(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)
```

Comment: I should also note that I know using Regex with HTML is generally frowned upon.  I am just trying to update some existing code.

Comment: `(?s)\bVideo Conference ID:\s(?:.*?&gt;){2}(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)` - https://regex101.com/r/VFR4kI/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that seems to do it.  I will work through it and develop an understanding.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Commenter provided the following.

```
    (?s)\bVideo Conference ID:\s(?:.*?&gt;){2}(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)
```